# how to connect to openwrt on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, openwrt

I have installed openwrt-x86-generic-combined.ext4.vdi on virtualbox. I set up the wan, so the "router" is connected to the network and i am able to ping sites with both ip and domain name.

Now I want to connect to the router with my windows laptop on which i have the virtual box running. I tried to follow this solution: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/virtualbox but it doesn't seem to connect.

My /etc/config/network file looks like this now:

```
 config interface 'wan'
                  option  proto 'dhcp'
                  option ifname 'eth0'

 config interface 'lan'
        option ifname 'eth2'
        option type 'bridge'
        option proto 'static' 
        option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
        option netmask '255.255.255.0'
```

I have tried to set the adapter to host-only, internal network and bridged adapter but none of them worked as I desired (didn't work at all actually), is there any way to do so?

Comment: New wiki page https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/virtualization/virtualbox-vm
Also simpler instruction  https://gist.github.com/stokito/533e2c1d2bc7809ceed124da3ab48567

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Adapter 1: NAT
Adapter 2: Host-Only

The host-only adapter I have configured in Vbox to 192.168.56.1
In openwrt I set the 'lan' ip to 192.168.56.2 which I can then ssh into

Your lan config says "eth2". should properly be "eth1"
https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/howto/virtualbox